# Hamburger menu with shrinking header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to merge a menu I have been working on with a shrinking header (though i want the hamburger to stay the same size).

I have tried directly merging piece of I found of a shrinking header with my hamburger menu, though there are conflicts where the overlay goes behind the header. Also can't get the logo text to be central, or get the bar itself to resize.

Here is my attempt: http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/XjQQWZ

And here is the previous and working version of the menu: http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/zKXARr

Any help would be great.

HTML

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko" rel="stylesheet"> 

<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            LOGO
        </h1>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
          <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="text">MENU</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header><!-- /header -->

 <nav>
        <ul role="navigation" class="overlay hidden">
            <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">RESUME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
 </nav>

<div class="contacts">
      <address>someperson@somewhere.com</address>
</div>

<div class="bigtext">THIS IS PLACEHOLDER</div>
```

CSS

```
    @import "compass/css3";

$bar-width: 50px;
$bar-height: 4px;
$bar-spacing: 15px;

body {
    background: #000000;
  font-family: Teko;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 45px;
  left: 45px;
  margin: auto;
  width: $bar-width;
    height: $bar-height + $bar-spacing*2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
    margin-left: 60px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.show .text {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX( -10px );
}


.bar,
.bar:after,
.bar:before {
  width: $bar-width;
    height: $bar-height;
}

.bar {
    position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY($bar-spacing);
    background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
    transition: all 0ms 300ms;

  .show & {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
  }
}

.bar:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    bottom: $bar-spacing;
    background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.bar:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: $bar-spacing;
    background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
    transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.show .bar:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
}

.show .bar:before {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1em;
  border-color: black;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #bc31fe;
}
nav ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Teko;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;

  &.hidden {
    display: none;
  }

    a {
    @include transition-duration(0.5s);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}

.overlay .contacts {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 37px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .01em;
    z-index: 2;
}
.contacts {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #10131a;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

.bigtext {
  font-size: 50em;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #0683c9;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}
header h1#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    float: center;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
header nav a {
    line-height: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #9fdbfc;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}
header.smaller {
    height: 75px;
}
header.smaller h1#logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
header.smaller nav a {
    line-height: 75px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
    header h1#logo {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    header nav {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    header nav a {
        line-height: 50px;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    header.smaller {
        height: 75px;
    }
    header.smaller h1#logo {
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    header.smaller nav {
        height: 35px;
    }
    header.smaller nav a {
        line-height: 35px;
    }
}
```

JS

```
( function () {

    var $navUL = $( 'nav ul' );

    $( '.hamburger-menu' ).on( 'click', function () {

        $( this ).toggleClass( 'show' );
        $navUL.toggleClass( 'hidden' );

    } );

} )();

function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Comment: Oh and here is the original code of the shrinking header http://codepen.io/Nickies/pen/ZYwJZM

Comment: you kind of vaguely mentioned a bunch of different things. try to be more specific about what problem you are having. saying "i want my website to look like this website, but it doesn't" is not appropriately specific. try breaking your problem down into a number of smaller problem, and try to solve them individually. and then if you run into issues with those smaller problems, make another SO post that specifies: your intended results, your actual result, what you tried to do to solve it, and your code.

Comment: Not sure how I can make it more specific... I want my hamburger menu http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/zKXARr to work with this http://codepen.io/Nickies/pen/ZYwJZM without it breaking like it does in my example...